# Oracle to Postgres Conversion trouble shooting

Tags: plpgsql, postgresql-9.5

Converted a Standalone Procedure from Oracle to Postgres but not sure why there is an run error even the code is successfully compiled

Converted the below code from Oracle to Postgres

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ssp2_pcat.pop_hoa_contracts_for_prod(
)
RETURNS void
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

COST 100
VOLATILE 
AS $BODY$

DECLARE 
C1 CURSOR for
SELECT MARKET_CODE, CONTRACT_COMBO_ID, COUNT(*) FROM 
ssp2_pcat.VPF_HOA_CONTRACTS_FOR_PROD A
WHERE start_Date IN
  (SELECT MAX(start_date)
  FROM VPF_HOA_CONTRACTS_FOR_PROD b
  WHERE A.MARKET_CODE     = b.MARKET_CODE
  AND A.CONTRACT_COMBO_ID = b.CONTRACT_COMBO_ID
  AND A.CONTRACT_ID       = B.CONTRACT_ID
  AND b.start_date       <= current_date
  AND b.end_date          > current_date )
  GROUP BY MARKET_CODE, CONTRACT_COMBO_ID 
  ORDER BY MARKET_CODE, CONTRACT_COMBO_ID; 

C2 CURSOR(iMktCode VARCHAR, iCombo integer) for
SELECT MARKET_CODE, CONTRACT_COMBO_ID, CONTRACT_ID 
FROM ssp2_pcat.VPF_HOA_CONTRACTS_FOR_PROD A
WHERE start_Date IN
  (SELECT MAX(start_date)
  FROM ssp2_pcat.VPF_HOA_CONTRACTS_FOR_PROD b
  WHERE A.MARKET_CODE     = b.MARKET_CODE
  AND A.CONTRACT_COMBO_ID = b.CONTRACT_COMBO_ID
  AND A.CONTRACT_ID       = B.CONTRACT_ID
  AND b.start_date       <= current_date
  AND b.end_date          > current_date  )
  AND MARKET_CODE       = iMktCode
  AND CONTRACT_COMBO_ID = iCombo
  ORDER BY MARKET_CODE, CONTRACT_COMBO_ID, START_DATE;
Contracts     VARCHAR(32000);
Contract_Val1 VARCHAR(4000) := NULL;
Contract_Val2 VARCHAR(4000) := NULL;
Contract_Val3 VARCHAR(4000) := NULL;
Contract_Val4 VARCHAR(4000) := NULL;
Contract_Val5 VARCHAR(4000) := NULL;
Contract_Val6 VARCHAR(4000) := NULL;
Contract_Val7 VARCHAR(4000) := NULL;
Contract_Val8 VARCHAR(4000) := NULL;
Num           INTEGER;
Cont_Num      INTEGER;
l_start TIMESTAMP :=  clock_timestamp();
l_end TIMESTAMP :=  clock_timestamp();
Time_Taken    VARCHAR(20);
                    i record;
                    j record;

BEGIN
l_start  :=  clock_timestamp();
DELETE FROM ssp2_pcat.HOA_CONTRACTS_KH; 
 FOR i IN C1 LOOP 
 BEGIN
 Num       := 0;
  Contracts := NULL;
  Cont_Num  := 1;        
 FOR j IN C2 (i.MARKET_CODE, i.CONTRACT_COMBO_ID) LOOP 
    Num         := Num + 1;
    IF Num       = 1 THEN
      Contracts := '|' || j.CONTRACT_ID || '|';
    ELSE
      IF LENGTH(Contracts || j.CONTRACT_ID || '|') > 4000 THEN
 PERFORM ssp2_pcat.Assign (Cont_Num, SUBSTRING(Contracts, 1, 
 LENGTH(Contracts)-1));
        Num       := 1;
        Contracts := '|' || j.CONTRACT_ID || '|';
        Cont_Num  := Cont_Num + 1;
      ELSE
        Contracts := Contracts || j.CONTRACT_ID || '|';
      END IF;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;                        
  PERFORM ssp2_pcat.Assign (Cont_Num, Contracts);
  IF Cont_Num > 5 THEN
    raise notice'%', ('MARKET_CODE: ' || i.MARKET_CODE || ', CONTRACT_COMBO_ID: ' || i.CONTRACT_COMBO_ID || ' has more than 32K in size. These Contracts are left out: ' || Contracts);
  END IF;
  INSERT INTO HOA_CONTRACTS_KH
    (
      MARKET_CODE,
      CONTRACT_COMBO_ID,
      CONTRACT_ID,
      CONTRACT_ID2,
      CONTRACT_ID3,
      CONTRACT_ID4,
      CONTRACT_ID5,
      LAST_UPDATED
    )
    VALUES
    (
      i.MARKET_CODE,
      i.CONTRACT_COMBO_ID,
      Contract_Val1,
      Contract_Val2,
      Contract_Val3,
      Contract_Val4,
      Contract_Val5,
      CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::TIMESTAMP(0)
    );
  Contract_Val1 := NULL;
  Contract_Val2 := NULL;
  Contract_Val3 := NULL;
  Contract_Val4 := NULL;
  Contract_Val5 := NULL;
  Contract_Val6 := NULL;
  Contract_Val7 := NULL;
  Contract_Val8 := NULL;

EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
  ROLLBACK;
  raise notice'%', ('1) POP_HOA_CONTRACTS_FOR_PROD: ' || SQLERRM);

END;
END LOOP;           
RAISE NOTICE 'Function excution time Took: %', l_start;
RAISE NOTICE 'Function excution time Took: %',l_end-l_start;
SELECT l_end-l_start INTO Time_Taken;
raise notice'%',('POP_HOA_CONTRACTS_FOR_PROD Took: ' || Time_Taken );
EXCEPTION
 WHEN OTHERS THEN
 raise notice'%', ('2) POP_HOA_CONTRACTS_FOR_PROD: ' || SQLERRM);

END;
$BODY$;
```

The code is compiled successfully, but giving a run time error as follows,

NOTICE:  2) POP_HOA_CONTRACTS_FOR_PROD: cannot begin/end transactions in PL/pgSQL

Debugged the whole code and looks like still I'm unable to identify the issue, can any one help me in making me understand more about Postgres as I'm new to this Database. Found out in unit testing that its not calling the assign function mentioned in the code,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL cannot begin/end transactions in PL/pgSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14550241/postgresql-cannot-begin-end-transactions-in-pl-pgsql)

Comment: @CodyCaughlan 
Rewrote the Function by bypassing the Calling Function Assign and now its working fine. Appreciate your time.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Thanks for looking into this!