# Looping through a CURSOR in PL/PGSQL without locking the table

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions, plpgsql, postgresql-9.5

I have a simple PL/PGSQL block **Postgres 9.5** that loops over records in a table and conditionally updates some of the records.

Here's a simplified example:

```sql
DO $$
  DECLARE

    -- Define a cursor to loop through records
    my_cool_cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT
      u.id          AS user_id,
      u.name        AS user_name,
      u.email       AS user_email
    FROM users u
    ;

  BEGIN

    FOR record IN my_cool_cursor LOOP

      -- Simplified example: 
      -- If user's first name is 'Anjali', set email to NULL
      IF record.user_name = 'Anjali' THEN
        BEGIN
          UPDATE users SET email = NULL WHERE id = record.user_id;
        END;
      END IF;

    END LOOP;
  END;

$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I'd like to execute this block directly against my database (from my app, via the console, etc...). I **do not** want to create a `FUNCTION()` or stored procedure to do this operation.

### The Issue

The issue is that the `CURSOR` and `LOOP` create a table-level lock on my `users` table, since everything between the outer `BEGIN...END` runs in a transaction. This blocks any other pending queries against it. If `users` is sufficiently large, this locks it up for several seconds or even minutes.

### What I tried

I tried to `COMMIT` after each `UPDATE` so that it clears the transaction and the lock periodically. I was surprised to see this error message:

```
ERROR:  cannot begin/end transactions in PL/pgSQL
HINT:  Use a BEGIN block with an EXCEPTION clause instead.
```

I'm not quite sure how this is done. Is it asking me to raise an `EXCEPTION` to force a `COMMIT`? I tried reading [the documentation on Trapping Errors](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING) but it only mentions `ROLLBACK`, so I don't see any way to `COMMIT`.

1. How do I periodically `COMMIT` a transaction inside the `LOOP` above?
2. More generally, is my approach even correct? Is there a better way to loop through records without locking up the table?

Comment: The cursor will not block other (read-only) queries. But I don't see the need for a (slow and inefficient) cursor to begin with

Answer (score 1):

#### 1.

You cannot `COMMIT` within a PostgreSQL [`FUNCTION`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) or in a  [`DO`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html) command before Postgres 11 **at all** (using PL/pgSQL or any other PL). That's causing the error you reported (for Postgres 9.5):

> ```
> ERROR:  cannot begin/end transactions in PL/pgSQL
> ```

A [`PROCEDURE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createprocedure.html) or `DO` statement in Postgres 11 or later can `COMMIT`. See:

- [PostgreSQL cannot begin/end transactions in PL/pgSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14550241/postgresql-cannot-begin-end-transactions-in-pl-pgsql/14550315#14550315)
- [In PostgreSQL, what is the difference between a “Stored Procedure” and other types of functions?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/194811/3684)

There are limited workarounds to achieve "autonomous transactions" in older versions:

- [How do I do large non-blocking updates in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113277/how-do-i-do-large-non-blocking-updates-in-postgresql/22163648#22163648)
- [Does Postgres support nested or autonomous transactions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25425944/does-postgres-support-nested-or-autonomous-transactions/25428060#25428060)
- [Does a procedure run in a transaction in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28250376/do-stored-procedures-run-in-database-transaction-in-postgres/28251922#28251922)

But you do not need any of this for the presented case.

#### 2.

Use a simple `UPDATE` instead:

```
UPDATE users
SET    email = NULL
WHERE  user_name = 'Anjali'
AND    email IS DISTINCT FROM NULL;  -- optional improvement
```

Only locks the rows that are actually updated (with corner case exceptions). And since this is *much* faster than a `CURSOR` over the whole table, the lock is also very brief.

The added `AND email IS DISTINCT FROM NULL` avoids empty updates. Related:

- [Update a column of a table with a column of another table in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13473499/update-a-column-of-a-table-with-a-column-of-another-table-in-postgresql?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns/12632129#12632129)

I hardly ever use explicit cursors in PL/pgSQL functions.

Comment: Thanks. The `UPDATE` statement I gave was just a simplified example. My real logic is much more complex, so I don't think I can do it in a single UPDATE as a workaround.

Comment: @user2490003: You still might. Maybe worth another question with details ...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid locking rows for a long time, you could also define a cursor `WITH HOLD`, for example using the [`DECLARE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-declare.html) SQL statement.

Such cursors can be used across transaction boundaries, so you could `COMMIT` after a certain number of updates. The price you are paying is that the cursor has to be materialized on the database server.

Since you cannot use transaction statements in functions, you will either have to use a procedure or commit in your application code.